# Flask doesn't stream on Lambda

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I have a small Flask app, which streams back some data

```
def start(self):
    for website in self.websites:
        yield self._do_something(website)
```

Which I call in app.py with `return Response(foo.start())`. Locally content will stream as expected, but on dev instance ([Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) + AWS Lambda) it will return all data at once, which is not desired.

I can't recreate this locally, why is this happening?

Comment: The zappa server has a 40ms lifetime. Might be that is what causes your problem. Taken from https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa. Maybe your developer friend will read the full documentation before using miracle serverless wonder environments next time. Another interesting side effect of using Zappa + AWS is that if your application somehow generates more than 1k simultaneous executions for one function, you'll start getting interesting results. That is another interesting gotcha that is documented in their Readme files.

Comment: There are only about 10 consecutive executions, so no issues there. I was aware of the 40ms lifetime, but wasn't sure it has an effect on this (though it does seem obvious).

Comment: @BoboDarph although there are many opportunities for sarcastic commentary, facepalms, RTFM, and LMGTFY here, (1) [they are best not taken](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), and (2) this does not appear to be one of them.  The "40ms lifecycle" is only a talking point... apparently an approximate *best case* performance for generating a response with Zappa and Lambda and API Gateway -- it's not a runtime limitation.  That would be arbitrary and a bit ridiculous.

Comment: Then I would like to apologize for the sarcasm in my answer, as it was not intended.

Comment: Amazon lambda now supports streaming: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/ so maybe Zappa will make use of that in a future version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue is related to the design of the services -- specifically, the interfaces they expose.

Both API Gateway and AWS Lambda use an *en bloc* request-response model for their interactions.

API Gateway parses the HTTP request, then generates a Lambda `Invoke` request, signs it, and passes it to Lambda... all at once.

Lambda runs your code, which either fails and generates an error response, or succeeds and generates a successful response, and passes it back to API Gateway... all at once.

API Gateway generates the final HTTP response, and passes it back to the browser... all at once.

Obviously the references to things happening "all at once" do not refer to the network layer, since all of the interactions occur over TCP... but at the higher layers, everything is discrete and complete.  There is no mechanism for anything other than returning the data all at once.

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense. I will rework endpoint to make separate requests to solve this.